What are red flags when it comes to choosing a PI?
I just finished my first postdoc and I had a terrible experience with my PI. Unfortunately, he is known in the field and I worked with him for two years and half. I've been to hell and back during this time. I don't want to repeat this experience ever again. He is not a bad boss. He is the enemy who tries to ruin everything, literally he was the only obstacle that I was facing during my postdoc. I can't count on his recommendation letter at all.
I worked with two other PIs during my PhD and I don't like to work with them again. They only think about how to take advantage of me without offering anything. It seems to me that this postdoc-PI relationship is very abusive in its own nature.
My experience with PIs so far hasn't been well. However, people say there are good PIs and I just were unlucky.
I talked to a new PI as a potential PI for my future postdoc. I thought he is nice but I realize that he is not easy to handle. He is not willing to listen to me and he only cares about his goals and his work which seems like a red flag to me.
Is this common or I'm unlucky in finding good PIs? Where should I draw the line while choosing a new supervisor? How much of abuse is normal in academia?
Edit: It seems that my question is not clear. By abusive behavior, I meant: lying, fabricating rules, stealing credit, humiliating in public, blame shifting for what is actually PI's fault, yelling, lack of open communication.
So the main question is: What are red flags when it comes to choosing a PI? What defines a toxic work environment?

There are (at least) two kinds of post docs. One in which the individual is very independent to follow their own course, and one in which you work for a "boss": the PI. This varies by field. I assume you are in a field with the latter expectation but you can't accept that. In such a field, I find little objectionable about the PI behavior you describe. You ain't the boss in such a situation.

Added after your edit: And were your previous PI experiences like that also? Lying, yelling, etc.

I don't think this post contains a directly answerable question. A good PI fit for one person may not be a good fit for another; there is no single line. What is an "average nice PI", anyways? What should a non-tautological answer to the question "what does an average nice PI look like" be?

My last postdoc was with a boss who lied about rules to prevent me from doing things. I have to check rules with a third party all the time. I even tried to submit a complain. The other postdoc in our group left in the middle of his contract. He is known for being a problematic PI. Thank you for the answer. I think I had incompetent  PhD PI and I learnt to be independent and it probably is inconsistent with my last workplace.

If a PI is known for being a problematic PI, don't work for them. Very very few people would lie about rules to prevent someone who works under them from doing things. There's just no logic to that: why would you hire someone that you want to impede? Instead, there are likely other explanations for the behavior you describe. Some might be selfish, some might be benign, but it's pretty hard for us to tell what's going on except to notice that you're upset.

When all three PIs you've had were "abusive" and so is the fourth, one must start to think about what connects them all ...

@BryanKrause We probably assume the OP is in the US or a country where there are controls about PI abuse. Maybe, however, that is not the case. In which case, OP probably needs to move to a country where the PI does not have unlimited power.

It is in Europe and PIs usually have unlimited power due to lack of systematic way to address problems. My PI lied and I double checked it with secretary to make sure he lied. Then I went to report it. Ombudsperson told me it is common in academia. Let it go.

If you find yourself repeatedly the victim of "bad" PIs perhaps you should also look at yourself. What is it that you are expecting that is not being met? Why was your prior advisor your enemy?
"unfortunately, he is known in the field" I should hope so otherwise why would they get funding for a postdoc, and why would anyone want to waste a postdoc working with them otherwise?
Why does your new potential PI need to be "easy to handle"? What does that mean? Why are you trying to handle your advisor? What is wrong with being goal and work driven within the context of explaining ones work to a potential postdoc? That is the role of a PI running a research enterprise. What do you want them to listen to you about? Have you advocated for yourself or are you expecting someone else to guess what your needs are?
"How much of abuse is normal in academia?" Depends what you describe as abuse. There is actual abuse which is wrong, and there is incompatible personalities and expectations. The latter doesn't feel great but is not abuse.

Thank you for your time but it wasn't answer to my question. It was just critisizing me. My question was how to draw the line with a new PI. Also, it is obvious what abusive behavior means. I want an enviorent that foster a postdoc growth, give them opportunities and help them advance their career. Not doing labor work and others get credit for it.

@Apostdoc This response was not a criticism. If you are unhappy with 4 PIs by now (I counted the ones you criticized), the question is really who needs to adjust their expectation. There is the occasional nasty PI. But if you encounter more then 2-3 in a row, then you may be doing something wrong, and that's what you have to find out - if you want to fix the issue, that is. "He is not willing to listen to me and he only cares about his goals and his work which seems like a red flag to me" - sorry, but that's perfectly legitimate behaviour. Of course the PI cares about his goals and work, as...

@Apostdoc .. as you do about yours. So, you need to find a PI whose goals are aligned with yours, especially if you are very specific about what you want to do. Note that if the PI gets funding from external funders, they may actually not have that much leeway anyway, as they have to fulfil their contract with the funder. So, you need to see, where are you willing to compromise, where is a red line you want to protect? You cannot have it all, unless you are absolutely brilliant, and even then it is difficult. Good luck.

@Apostdoc: imagine that someone asked you: “I’m trying to dig a hole, but I bought four different shovels and all four shattered within five minutes. Is this normal for shovels? How do I draw the line when I buy my fifth shovel?” Your question may be about shovels, but the answers will rightly focus on your unusually high shovel attrition rate. If you don’t want this, you might edit your post to better describe the specific problems you faced (not all the details, but more concrete than “he is the enemy” and “I went to hell and back.”)

I edited my question in order to clarify it. Also, I haven't got the answer yet. Thank you for your time. PS: It is very common to blame victims. People learnt not to blame rape victim by saying you dressed inappropriately or you were drunk but they haven't learned not to blame other types of victim. I understand the meaning of abuse, victim and a PI perspective. I hope I get a right answer this time.

@Apostdoc I don't think you'll be gaining yourself much support by equating your situation to rape.

I answer a lot of questions here and think about a lot of others, including this one. But I can't come up with a better answer than this one. I could only add: evaluate the likely compatibility before you accept any job.

I was not looking for support. I was looking for answer. However I think I got enough of answer here

The only answer is you get your own fellowship of postdoc, then you can control everything. You worked with 3 PIs and all of them are 'bad' in your mind, including one that is very famous. Did you consider that you are the one that is difficult to work with?

Thank you for your time. I consider that. I'm not the problem. I just didn't see red flags. So I wanted to know what are red flags when it comes to choose a PI. Abusive behaviors are well defined. I don't think it is my fault when my PI lies. How can it be my fault? There are many abusive PIs in academia. I just wanted to know how to spot them. Instead I got lots of criticism which is very disappointing.

It is because based on your question and response, most people here think that you have unrealistic expectations to advisor. Why don't you try to answer the question 'What is wrong with being goal and work driven within the context of explaining ones work to a potential postdoc?'

@Apostdoc It is not a question that there are abusive PIs. And they may lie, too. The question, however, indicates that you have a series of extraordinarily unlucky choices, which means that you somehow end up choosing the wrong ones. More surprising is that you didn't like them setting goals and expectations for you. Was that not agreed beforehand? Did they bait and switch you? I think this needs to be clarified in the question before we can help you. And yes, we would like to help you. One other thing may be the area you work in. Some communities are toxic overall.
